# Kusto : summarize and display the group as csv

Tags: azure-data-explorer

In the below query, I want to display the email-id and the unique-user-id for that user.

```
customEvents
   //| where customDimensions.UserId == 'Error'
     | where  timestamp > ago(2d)
     | summarize values = dcount(tostring(customDimensions.UserId)) by tostring(customDimensions.email)
```

Data :

```
UserId email
1      someone@x.com
Error  someone@x.com
2      other@x.com
3      otherother@x.com
Error  otherother@x.com
```

Expected Output:

```
someone@x.com.   1, Error
other@x.com      2
otherother@x.com 3, Error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try this:

```
datatable(UserId:string, Email:string)
[
    '1',     'someone@x.com',
    'Error', 'someone@x.com',
    '2',     'other@x.com',
    '3',     'otherother@x.com',
    'Error', 'otherother@x.com',
]
| summarize UserIds = strcat_array(make_set(UserId), ", ") by Email
```